# Find # of pages in a multipage table

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to extract the # of pages in a multipage table URL

```
HTML=<span style="float:right">Page 1 of 63,917</span>
```

Need to extract 63917.

I used

```
soup = bsoup(r.text)
pages=re.findall(r"Page 1 of\s(.+)<\/span>", str(soup))
print(pages)
```

But the print(pages) returns a whole lot of HTML right till the end of the body

```
##'63,917</span></div><table class="table table-striped##
```

Why doesn't my regex work? And how do i extract only the # from the HTML response?

Comment: Have you really looked into `BeautifulSoup` (the object `soup` lets me assume it) ? It's really a breeze there.

Comment: You have a lot of inconsistencies in your code. What is `soup`? Why do you need a `"\"` in a raw string? `print(pages)` must print a list, not an element. Please provide a reproducible example. Finally, do not use regex to parse HTML files.

Comment: yeah i am using beautifulsoup. In fact the soup corresponds to the HTML response.But not sure why the findall captures all the remaining HTML and not just return the #. Also yeah print(pages) will return a list, and i hope to extract the 1st element into an integer. But pages has more than the #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not work because you are using greedy capture in your grouping parentheses `(.+)`. The way you have it written, the `.+` is matching everything from `Page 1 of\s` onward (until the last `</span>` tag in the document). You need to use [non-greedy](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) capture by adding a `?` after the `+`, like this:

```
Page 1 of\s(.+?)<\/span>
```